# Configuring DbContext for InMemoryDatabase that also depends on IOptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, xunit.net

I want to create InMemoryDatabase for unit testing.

My DbContext is deriving from `ApiAuthorizationDbContext<ApplicationUser>` and I cannot instantiate my DbContext in test code because `operationalStoreOptions` is missing from constructor.

What should I do to create `operationalStoreOptions` for my context?

**DbContext**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : ApiAuthorizationDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
   
    public ApplicationDbContext(
                DbContextOptions options,
                IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions) : base(options, operationalStoreOptions) { }

    public virtual DbSet<Assignment> Assignment { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Course> Course { get; set; } 
                           ...........
    // More DbSet and OnModelCreating method
 }
```

**My test code**

```
 var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
           .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "TestDbContext")
           .Options;
    

 //ApplicationDbContext needs 2 constructor parameter
 using (var _context = new ApplicationDbContext(options))
 {
   _context.Assignment.Add(new Assignment(1, "Test"));
   _context.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Comment: Do you need for your test the IdentityServer4 service? if not you could make another constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should I do to create operationalStoreOptions for my context?

Create an instance of the desired type, populate as needed for the test case and then use [`Options.Create<TOptions>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.options.create) to get the desired `IOptions` to inject into the context constructor

```
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "TestDbContext")
    .Options;

OperationalStoreOptions storeOptions = new OperationalStoreOptions {
    //populate needed members
};

IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions = Options.Create(storeOptions);

//ApplicationDbContext needs 2 constructor parameter
using (var _context = new ApplicationDbContext(options, operationalStoreOptions)) {
    _context.Assignment.Add(new Assignment(1, "Test"));
    _context.SaveChanges();
}

//...
```